# Data Backfill of Facebook Ads to Bigquery (with Segment)

Tags: google-bigquery, facebook-ads-api, segment

I am using Segment for a data transfer for facebook ads data to Google BigQuery.
The Transfer is set up since yesterday. Now i can display only the curent status and by  querying the changelog I can query data based on a specific date.
Des anyone now how I can set up a Data Backfill of facebook ads data to BigQuery ? Preferably with segment but aso with other solutions.

Comment: If my answer addressed your question, please consider accepting and upvoting it. If not, let me know so that I can improve my answer.Accepting an answer will help the community members with their research as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the public [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/dts-introduction?hl=en_US#supported_data_sources) , currently the BigQuery Data Transfer Service does not support loading data from Facebook ads but you can use third party transfer to do the same. You can follow this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/third-party-transfer?hl=en_US#set_up_a_third_party_data_transfer) regarding data transfer using a third party tool. Before doing that also make sure that you have the required permissions by following this [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/third-party-transfer?hl=en_US#before_you_begin). After setting up a third party data transfer you can follow below steps for data backfill.

Step 1:  Go to the BigQuery console and click `transfer`.

Step 2:  Find the transfer you created for facebook ads and click on that transfer.

Step 3:  Now you can see the `more` button on the top right corner of the console and click on that `more` button and select schedule backfill.

Step 4:  Now you can choose the start and end date.

Step 5:  Click the `ok` button.

You can also check out this similar YT [tuotorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IuJ2Zaq15j4) video for setup data backfill. Here a third party tool Supermetrics has been used to initiate data transfer.